# Get an image through image path Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am developing a little project for school where I have to get some information from this db: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=a4571caf3b2611c1effc82a2c8323b15&language=en-US&page=1

I would like to get the image thats in ["poster_path"] and put it into a tableView.
For other images I did this: `cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(named: llibre.img)`

but for a path, it doesn't work. I have already connected the bd to the project.

path example: "poster_path":"/jjPJ4s3DWZZvI4vw8Xfi4Vqa1Q8.jpg"

I have tried to replace "name" for path, and other silly things that doesn't work.

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(path: \/jjPJ4s3DWZZvI4vw8Xfi4Vqa1Q8.jpg)
```

Any help would be very useful. Sorry for my english, it's not my native language.
Thank you

Comment: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/images Please have a look at this you need to append tase url with size to get image details of movie

Comment: you should have the base url like https://youwebsite.com/jjPJ4s3DWZZvI4vw8Xfi4Vqa1Q8.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Tmdb Document](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/images) 
You can concatenation the return value from api  with this value 
 `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/`

result example : http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185//xmgAsda5sPNpx5ghJibJ80S7Pfx.jpg

This is value `w185` for image size